# How do I give permission to my users to upload a big file size using Easy Digital Downloads Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the plugin Easy Digital Downloads in my website. The website idea is to sell 3D models to be used in games. Customers has to upload either unity packages or auto disk Maya. The files are large. So I am using Easy Digital Downloads Plugins to allow users to upload their files. The problem is that the clients are getting HTTP Error while trying to upload. So they send me the files and I upload them into the server and then I reassign those files to the clients. It is a headache to me. I am trying to create and easy and simple solution for everyone to use my website. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?
Regards,

wp-config, .htaccess, php.ini

Comment: Have you tried increasing the upload_max_filesize in your php ini file

Comment: yes I did. The upload file size is set to 4GB. I don't know what causes this problem

Comment: and the post_max_size ?

Comment: the same file size. 4GB

Comment: should I upgrade mysql 5.6 to mariadb 10.2?

Comment: Also I suggest change `max_execution_time` if files are big, it takes lot of time to upload them, by default on servers thisparameter is 30s